# Wordpress режет html комментарии в шаблоне

Tags: wordpress

Имею в wordpress шаблоне такой кометарий <!-- qweqweqwe -->. При рендеринге страницы этого комментария нету в исходном коде страницы! Подскажите пожалуйста что может резать данный коммент и как отключить обрезание.

Answer (score 1):

Ты чё-то путаешь. По умолчанию ничего не вырезается: http://demo.opensourcecms.com/wordpress/

Может у тебя стоят какие-нибудь сторонние плагины, по типу WP minify ?

Comment: Предположу еще, что, возможно, у автора подключается не тот файл, который он редактирует.

Comment: правлю файл тот точно инфа 100%, посмотрю на счет плагинов

Comment: @greshnik, тут через вопрос инфа 100%. Проверьте еще наличие и работу кэша.